# create parallel stage Map using collectEntries from List Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, collections, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

First Stage I want to check all the Agents and write those which are online into a `onlineNodes` List.
Similar to the sample : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/nodes/.
After that I want to run Steps on all online Agents. But it seems like I can't get the `onlineNodes` List correctly out of the `@NonCPS` function. Thanks!

```
@NonCPS
def checkAgent() {
       //stage(computer.name) {
    def numberOfflineNodes = 0
    def numberNodes = 0
    def jenkins = Jenkins.instance
    def nodes = jenkins.getNodes()
    def onlineNodes =[]
    def offlineNodes = []
    
    nodes.each { agent ->
       def computer = agent.computer
       numberNodes ++
       println ""
       println "Checking computer ${computer.name}:"
        
        //    objNode = new Object();
           def isOK = (agentAccessible(computer) && !computer.offline)
           if (isOK) {
             println "\t\tOK, got PATH back from agent ${computer.name}."
             println('\tcomputer.isOffline: ' + computer.isOffline());
             println('\tcomputer.isTemporarilyOffline: ' + computer.isTemporarilyOffline());
            //  onlineNodes += computer.name;
               onlineNodes += computer.name
           } else {
             println "\t\tERROR: can't get PATH from agent ${computer.name}."
             println('\tcomputer.isOffline: ' + computer.isOffline());
             println('\tcomputer.isTemporarilyOffline: ' + computer.isTemporarilyOffline());
             println('\tcomputer.getOfflineCause: ' + computer.getOfflineCause());
             numberOfflineNodes ++;
            //  offlineNodes += computer.name;
            offlineNodes.push(computer)
            //   objNode =  { name: computer.name, isOffline: computer.isOffline(), provetechOnline: false};
             if (computer.isTemporarilyOffline()) {
               if (!computer.getOfflineCause().toString().contains("Disconnected by")) {
                 computer.setTemporarilyOffline(false, agent.getComputer().getOfflineCause())
               }
             } else {
                 computer.connect(true)      
             }
            }
    
        }
         return onlineNodes;
}
@NonCPS
def getEnviron(computer) {
   def env
   def thread = Thread.start("Getting env from ${computer.name}", { env = computer.environment })
   thread.join(2000)
   if (thread.isAlive()) thread.interrupt()
   env
}

@NonCPS
def agentAccessible(computer) {
    getEnviron(computer)?.get('PATH') != null
}
```

Inside the Pipeline I have:

```
def generateStage(nodeLabel) {
    return {
        stage("Runs on ${nodeLabel}") {
            node (nodeLabel) {
                
                echo "We run on ${nodeLabel}"
            }
        } 
    }
}

def groovyNodes =[]
def cpyNode = ["Kaelans PC"]
def parallelStagesMap = cpyNode.collectEntries {
        ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
    }

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Check Agents') {
            steps {
                script {                    
                 groovyNodes = checkAgent()
                }
            }
        }

        stage('parallel stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    groovyNodes.each{ node ->
                        echo new JsonBuilder( node ).toPrettyString()
                    }
                    cpyNode.each{ node ->
                        echo new JsonBuilder( node ).toPrettyString()
                    }               
                    parallel parallelStagesMap
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I use cpyNodes as test example the code run correctly as I expected but if I use the return value from `checkAgent()` it fails to find Nodes. The string outputs of `groovyNodes` and `cpyNode` seem to be identical though.

the Output:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (parallel stage)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
"Kaelans PC"
[Pipeline] echo
"Kaelans PC"
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] { (Branch: Kaelans PC)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Runs on Kaelans PC)
[Pipeline] node
Running on Kaelans PC in C:\Custom Programs\Jenkins\workspace\Check Agents@2
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
We run on Kaelans PC
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

Edited:
If I use the `groovyNodes` List which contains the return value of `checkAgent()`

```
def parallelStagesMap = groovyNodes.collectEntries {
        ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
    }
```

I get following Output:

```
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (parallel stage)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
"Kaelans PC"
[Pipeline] echo
"Kaelans PC"
[Pipeline] parallel
No branches to run
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

So in the end I have 2 ArrayLists with seeming identical values but `collectEntries()` react different, Why?

Comment: Why do you think it's incorrect? What's your question?

Comment: sorry, I didn't make it clear enough. If I use the List `groovyNodes` which contains the return value of `checkAgent()`. I get following Output: <br/>`[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (parallel stage)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
"Kaelans PC"
[Pipeline] echo
"Kaelans PC"
[Pipeline] parallel
No branches to run
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage`

Comment: edit your question and make it clear - it's impossible to read formatted text in comments.

Comment: I did it, look at the edit part, thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Define `parallelStagesMap` inside stage solved the Problem.

```
def groovyNodes =[]

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Check Agents') {
            steps {
                script {                    
                 groovyNodes = checkAgent()
                 groovyNodes.each{ node ->
                        echo "groovyNodes: " + new JsonBuilder( node ).toPrettyString()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('parallel stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def parallelStagesMap = groovyNodes.collectEntries {
                        ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]   
                    }               
                    parallel parallelStagesMap
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```